# _OBJC_CLASS_$ Error in iOS application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_AddViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-AddViewController in ContactsController.o

ld: symbol(s) not found

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

and the particular controllers are attached and compiling fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Make sure that AddViewController.m is added to your compile sources.

Comment: In XCode 4 you need to select your target, go to build phases, then compile sources. When you expand compile sources you will see a + at the bottom you can use to add the source file. If it is already included it will be grayed out and you have another issue otherwise add it.

Comment: This can also occur after you have deleted a file, remember to clean Shft+Cmd+K as this can often clean the problem away

Comment: I deleted the .m, as I thought my simple class didn't need it. Spoiler alert: it needs it. Even if empty.